# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'taxonomy_features' error occurs when I tried to retrieve some data from the database

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

when retrieving data from the database there is an error.
Error is

> File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/first/zb.py", line 58, in classify
>
> featuresets = [(self.taxonomy_features(tuple), taxonomy) for (tuple, taxonomy) in labeled_names]
>
> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'taxonomy_features'

```
import the MySQLdb and sys modules
import MySQLdb
import sys

class z:
    def taxonomy_features(self, tuple):
        features = {}

        features["course_id"] = tuple[1]
        features["userid_DI"] = tuple[2]
        features["registered"] = tuple[3]
        features["viewed"] = tuple[4]
        features["explored"] = tuple[5]
        features["certified"] = tuple[6]
        features["final_cc_cname_DI"] = tuple[7]
        features["LoE_DI"] = tuple[8]
        features["YoB"] = tuple[9]
        features["gender"] = tuple[10]
        features["grade"] = tuple[11]
        features["start_time_DI"] = tuple[12]
        features["last_event_DI"] = tuple[13]
        features["nevents"] = tuple[14]
        features["ndays_act"] = tuple[15]
        features["nplay_video"] = tuple[16]
        features["nchapters"] = tuple[17]
        features["nforum_post"] = tuple[18]
        features["roles"] = tuple[19]
        features["incomplete_flag"] = tuple[20]
        features["grade1"] = tuple[21]
        features["result"] = tuple[22]

        return features

    def classify(self):

        # open a database connection
        # be sure to change the host IP address, username, password and database name to match your own
        connection = MySQLdb.connect (host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "", db = "student")

        # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
        cursor = connection.cursor ()

        # execute the SQL query using execute() method.
        cursor.execute ("select * from mytable")

        # fetch all of the rows from the query
        data = cursor.fetchall ()

        # print the rows


        labeled_names = ([(dataRecord, dataRecord[21]) for dataRecord in data])
        print(labeled_names)
        featuresets = [(self.taxonomy_features(tuple), taxonomy) for (tuple, taxonomy) in labeled_names]
        print(featuresets)

        # close the cursor object
        cursor.close ()

        # close the connection
        connection.close ()

        # exit the program
        sys.exit()

    classify(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Indent classify method and re-write its signature like:
`def classify(self, my_parameter):`

Then when you try to call it you will call it like `z().classify(1)` Right now the method is not an instance method since it does not belong to your your z class.